# How do I compare two functions' speed and performance

Tags: c++, performance, comparison

I have two functions performing same process but with different techniques and I need to know on a large scale which technique is faster than the other of maybe in the future will be more techniques available. So my question is, how can I do that in c++ specially? Is there a specific method and header to be used to perform this task?

More details:
For example the isLargest() uses three parameters and it has two versions, one uses a nested if technique and the other uses initializers and less if statements. So if I need to know which one is faster, how can I do that?

Comment: Sometimes  you have to generate random data and run each algorithm several thousand times with the same data being careful to do something with the result so the the optimizer does not determine that the calculation is pointless and totally eliminate the calculation. Benchmarking can be a complex subject.

Comment: Its depends upon the complexity of the function . What exactly do u want to knw .

Comment: You might be able to use [Quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/)

Answer (score 1):

**Try your code in the real world and measure**

There is a tool called a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) that is meant to solve this problem. Broadly speaking, there are two kinds (note: some are a mix between the two):

- Sampling profilers.
- Instrumenting profilers.

It's worth learning about what each does and their pros/cons, but if you don't know what to use go with a sampling profiler.

There are many sampling profilers, but support depends on your platform. If you're on Windows, [Visual Studio comes with a really nice sampling profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) and I recommend you start there!

If you go down this route, it's important to make sure you use your functions as you would "for real" when you're profiling them, as there are many subtle factors that can affect the result.

**An alternative**

If you don't want to try your code running in a real program, perhaps if you're just trying to understand general characteristics of the function, there are libraries to help you do this such as [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

Benchmarking code can be surprisingly difficult to get right, so I would strongly recommend using existing benchmarking tools where like [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) wherever possible.